# I was writing a function for finding if a number is palindrome or not. It gives me a runtime error on line 2 which is the function defining line

Tags: python, function, runtime-error, palindrome

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x: int) -> bool  :
        if x < 0:
            return(False)
        
      
        rev_num=0
        digit=0
        
        while(x // (10 ** digit) != 0):
           
            #rev_num = rev_num + ((x * (10 ** digit) ) + (x % 10)) % 10
            rev_num= (rev_num * 10) + (x // (10 ** digit ) % 10) 
            digit += 1
            
        return (rev_num == x)
```

Comment: Try running this is locally and try to get a better error. It may be that their interpreter is too old to recognize type hints.

Comment: how is this function being called?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're solving [LeetCode 9](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/), for which this solution would pass:

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        if x < 0 or (x > 0 and not x % 10):
            return False
        
        return str(x) == str(x)[::-1]
```

Or similar to your method (for the follow up question):

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        if x < 0 or (x and not x % 10):
            return False

        summation = 0
        while x > summation:
            summation *= 10
            summation += x % 10
            x //= 10

        return x == summation or x == summation // 10
```

```
class Solution:
    def isPalindrome(self, x):
        if x < 0:
            return False

        divisor = 1
        while x // divisor >= 10:
            divisor *= 10

        while divisor > 1:
            left, x = divmod(x, divisor)
            x, right = divmod(x, 10)
            if left != right:
                return False
            divisor //= 100

        return True
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-number/discuss/). There are plenty of accepted solutions, explanations, efficient algorithms with a variety of languages, and time/space complexity analysis in there.